# Ajustar texto no recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa noite!
Estou com dificuldades em ajustar o texto de um textview dentro de uma lista, como mostra a imagem, o final do texto está sobrepondo o botão. Como corrigir? Imagem de como está ficando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_status"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:id="@+id/item_date" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/item_action"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
    android:alpha="0.26" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Experimente colocar `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_action"` no LinearLayout

Comment: Deu certo. Vlw!